# Micropython not finding any module attributes

Tags: python, micropython

I'm writing a set of functions for my esp8266 (running micropython) to send data to a server via `urequests` but can't import the functions into my main.py. I've successfully created modules for other tasks and imported them, but when I have this in netclient.py

```
import urequests

def postData(data_dict, url="http://192.168.1.1:9000/weather_station"):

    try:
        response = urequests.post(url,
            headers = {'Connection': 'Close', 'content-type': 'application/json'},
            json = data_dict)
    except OSError as e:
        print("Error sending packet: {} \n retrying...".format(e))
        try:
            response = urequests.post(url,
                headers={'Connection': 'Close', 'content-type': 'application/json'},
                json = data_dict)
        except OSError as e:
            print("Error sending packet: {} \n retry failed".format(e))
            response = False
    return response
```

Then when I try this from the webrepl

```
import netclient
netclient.postData()
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'postData'
```

When I inspect `netclient`, its only attributes are `__class__` and `__name__`

Where am I going wrong?

The file system looks like this

```
import os 
os.listdir()
['boot.py', 'credentials.json', 'netclient.py', 'lib', 'main.py', 'sensors.py', 'webrepl_cfg.py', 'wifi.py']
```

Comment: does `netclient` import `web_repl`? Can you provide the full directory structure? Is the root named `netclient` by any chance?

Comment: I added an `import webrepl` to netclient, but it didn't change anything. What I've listed is the root filesystem, this is a simple microcontroller

Comment: Is the root directory named `netclient`? If so, then you must try something like `from netclient import netclient`, and then use `netclient.postData()`

Comment: @pgcudahy please actually try to answer my questions. I wasn't suggesting you import `netclient` in `web_repl`, *I was asking you* because a circular import might cause thise. Furthermore, please provide the full structure, with the actual name of the directory. Don't make us guess. It doesn't matter if it is shallow. We need a way to actually reproduce this, and what you've provided is not sufficient.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not being clear, but this is the *root* directory, there is no directory name or further structure. http://docs.micropython.org/en/v1.9.1/esp8266/esp8266/tutorial/filesystem.html. Also to be clear, I have included the entire code of netclient.py in my question. It does not import anything besides `urequests`